# Is it possible to expand CTI Phone when it's collapsed from sforce.console.cti api?

Tags: console, cti

Is it possible to expand CTI Phone when it's collapsed from sforce.console.cti api?  I have custom CTI phone implementation and I need to expand it if it's collapsed.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this by  setting true to the `.setVisible()` method as below. Please refer this [Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_setvisible.htm) for details. Hope this helps.

```
sforce.interaction.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Hi guys. Asking this question here since you guys have worked on CTI . Activity History records are not getting created automatically after call . What could be the possible reasons?

Comment: Are you using the standard History component?

Comment: @SarojBera- We are using task

Comment: Can it be due to WhoID missing?

Comment: @SarojBera Hi Saroj . Any idea on why it's happening?

Comment: For some reason the method is not working at all. Any clue ? Tried in different org, first it worked and then again issue started.